# ERROR org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin:335 - Error scheduling jobs: Jobs added with no trigger must be durable

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Everything seems to working perfectly with Quartz but I am getting the below stack trace when starting my application

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Jobs added with no trigger must be durable.
at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.addJob(QuartzScheduler.java:916)
at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.addJob(StdScheduler.java:269)
at org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.scheduleJobs(XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.java:1069)
at org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.processFileAndScheduleJobs(XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.java:888)
at org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.processFile(XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.java:330)
at org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.start(XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.java:257)
at org.quartz.plugins.SchedulerPluginWithUserTransactionSupport.start(SchedulerPluginWithUserTransactionSupport.java:144)
at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.startPlugins(QuartzScheduler.java:2343)
at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:527)
at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:143)
at org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet.init(QuartzInitializerServlet.java:211)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

The jobs schedule in the quartz-config.xml seem to fire fine and so do all jobs that are schedule programmatically

Any idea what is causing this?

Here is the config file which seems correct to me

```
<schedule>
    <job>
        <name>ProcessLeadsJob</name>
        <group>PROCESS_LEAD_JOB_GROUP</group>
        <description>This job process the leads every 24 hours.</description>
        <job-class>ClassName</job-class>
    </job>

    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>processLeadsJobTrigger</name>
            <job-name>ProcessLeadsJob</job-name>
            <job-group>PROCESS_LEAD_JOB_GROUP</job-group>
            <cron-expression>0 0 00 * * ?</cron-expression>
        </cron>
    </trigger>
</schedule>
```

Answer (score 6):

It depends what version of Quartz you are using.

As the error message is suggesting you, you need to make this job durable i.e. you need to add the tag for durability e.g.

```
<schedule>
<job>
    <name>ProcessLeadsJob</name>
    <group>PROCESS_LEAD_JOB_GROUP</group>
    <description>This job process the leads every 24 hours.</description>
    <job-class>ClassName</job-class>
    <!-- here you add the tags that are need it-->
    <durability>true</durability>
    <!--I am using quartz 2 and there is mandatory to have recover tag specified --> 
   <recover>false</recover>
</job>

<trigger>
    <cron>
        <name>processLeadsJobTrigger</name>
        <job-name>ProcessLeadsJob</job-name>
        <job-group>PROCESS_LEAD_JOB_GROUP</job-group>
        <cron-expression>0 0 00 * * ?</cron-expression>
    </cron>
</trigger>
```

In order to know if your quartz-config.xml file is ok check it against one of the following schema depending on your version of quartz:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_2_0.xsd

good luck :)

Comment: Where the above tags has to be added and how ? Can you please explain ?

Comment: I just update my answer so that it's shows where the tags are need it. Also you can look at the xsd files to see where the tags are need it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing something in the trigger during runtime?

If so, try adding this to your XML (before the  tag).

```
<pre-processing-commands>
    <delete-jobs-in-group>PROCESS_LEAD_JOB_GROUP</delete-jobs-in-group>
    <delete-triggers-in-group>PROCESS_LEAD_TRIGGER_GROUP</delete-triggers-in-group>
</pre-processing-commands>
```

And add a group to your trigger

```
<trigger>
    <cron>
        <name>processLeadsJobTrigger</name>
        <group>PROCESS_LEAD_TRIGGER_GROUP</group>
        <job-name>ProcessLeadsJob</job-name>
        <job-group>PROCESS_LEAD_JOB_GROUP</job-group>
        <cron-expression>0 0 00 * * ?</cron-expression>
    </cron>
</trigger>
```

So, your final XML may look something like this:

```
<pre-processing-commands>
    <delete-jobs-in-group>PROCESS_LEAD_JOB_GROUP</delete-jobs-in-group>
    <delete-triggers-in-group>PROCESS_LEAD_TRIGGER_GROUP</delete-triggers-in-group>
</pre-processing-commands>
<schedule>
    <job>
        <name>ProcessLeadsJob</name>
        <group>PROCESS_LEAD_JOB_GROUP</group>
        <description>This job process the leads every 24 hours.</description>
        <job-class>ClassName</job-class>
    </job>

    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>processLeadsJobTrigger</name>
            <group>PROCESS_LEAD_TRIGGER_GROUP</group>
            <job-name>ProcessLeadsJob</job-name>
            <job-group>PROCESS_LEAD_JOB_GROUP</job-group>
            <cron-expression>0 0 00 * * ?</cron-expression>
        </cron>
    </trigger>
</schedule>
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring context configuration and hence the below syntax makes more sense to me. But anyways your answers solved my issue.

```
<!-- Spring Quartz -->
<bean name="createProcDateJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">

    <property name="jobClass" value="com.poc.app.web.server.scheduler.createProcDateJob" />

    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="copyProdOutputTask" value-ref="copyProdOutputTask" />
        </map>
    </property>

    <property name="durability" value="true" />
</bean>
```